# Datagridview Dynamic cell calculation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two columns in Datagridview, one for the price excluding Vat and another one for price including Vat, I want it to be dynamic, if I alter the price excluding vat it updates the column including Vat, and if I Update the including Vat column it updates the excluding VAT column  vice-versa.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with the right code for it in C#.

Here´s the code I´m using the calculation to one direction I need the code for the inverse.

```
  private void dgv_Filho_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            bool Check = Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["Check_Filho"].Value);
            string Medida_1 = Convert.ToString(dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["Medida_1"].Value);
            string Medida_2 = Convert.ToString(dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["Medida_2"].Value);

            var Iva = Convert.ToDecimal(cb_Iva.Text);

            if (Check)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb_CodigoArtigo.Text) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb_Descricao.Text))
                {
                    dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["ArtigoPai"].Value = tb_CodigoArtigo.Text;
                    dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["Descricao_Pai"].Value = tb_Descricao.Text + " " + Medida_1 + Medida_2;
                    dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["CodigoArtigoFilho"].Value = tb_CodigoArtigo.Text + Medida_1 + Medida_2;
                    //dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["PrecoFilhoSemIva"].Value = tb_PVP1.Text;

                    decimal PrecoFilho = Convert.ToDecimal(dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["PrecoFilhoSemIva"].Value);
                    if (PrecoFilho > 0)
                    {
                        decimal PrecoFilhoComIva = PrecoFilho * Iva / 100 + PrecoFilho;
                        dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["PrecoFilhoComIva"].Value = PrecoFilhoComIva;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["ArtigoPai"].Value = string.Empty;
                    dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["Descricao_Pai"].Value = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information in your question for anyone to supply an answer. For example: are you using the Datagridview in VirtualMode, connected to database, ...? Show a little code of how you are using this control.

Comment: I do use database but I want this calculations to be done before I insert it to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't too difficult using your existing code:
First of all, use the name of the edited column in `if`/`else if` statements to filter which conversion should take place, so that changing the VAT column doesn't get overwritten by the preVAT column. Then, use the opposite algebraic expression of the one you already have written to convert the postVAT price back to the preVAT

Here is what it will look like:

```
dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["ArtigoPai"].Value = tb_CodigoArtigo.Text;
dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["Descricao_Pai"].Value = tb_Descricao.Text + " " + Medida_1 + Medida_2;
dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["CodigoArtigoFilho"].Value = tb_CodigoArtigo.Text + Medida_1 + Medida_2;
decimal PrecoFilho = Convert.ToDecimal(dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["PrecoFilhoSemIva"].Value);
decimal PrecoFilhoComIva = Convert.ToDecimal(dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["PrecoFilhoComIva"].Value);
if (dgv_Filho.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "PrecoFilhoSemIva")
{
    PrecoFilhoComIva = PrecoFilho * (Iva / 100) + PrecoFilho;
    dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["PrecoFilhoComIva"].Value = PrecoFilhoComIva;
}
else if (dgv_Filho.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "PrecoFilhoComIva")
{
    decimal PrecoFilhoSemIva = PrecoFilhoComIva - (PrecoFilhoComIva / (1 + (Iva / 100)) * (Iva / 100));
    dgv_Filho.CurrentRow.Cells["PrecoFilhoSemIva"].Value = PrecoFilhoSemIva;
}
```

Using this code, editing the preVAT value will automatically update the postVAT value accordingly, and editing the postVAT value will automatically update the preVAT value accordingly

Comment: I’m editing  directly into cells of the datagridview  before inserting to database, all I need is when I change the price without vat it automatically update the cell of vat included and if I change value of the vat included it changes the value of cell of without vat vice versa. I’m new in programming apologies If I’m unable to explain properly.

Comment: @HaricheArquissandas - Thank you for the clarification. I have updated my answer with the information you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Rather than interact with the `DataGridView` directly (which can be complex) you could instead make a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and keeps all of its internal calculations up-to-date at all times (which is easier). Here is a simplified version of such a class that responds to changes of `Descricao`, `Medida` and `PrecoFilhoSemIva`.

---

**Simplified class that represents a row of data**

```
class Articulo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    string _descricao = string.Empty;
    public string Descricao
    {
        get => _descricao;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_descricao, value))
            {
                _descricao = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Descricao_Pai => $"{Descricao} {Medida_1}@{_precoFilhoSemIva.ToString("F2")}";
    public decimal PrecoFilhoComIva => _precoFilhoSemIva * (1.0m + MainForm.Iva);

    decimal _medida = 0;
    public decimal Medida
    {
        get => _medida;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_medida, value))
            {
                _medida = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    decimal _precoFilhoSemIva = 0;
    public decimal PrecoFilhoSemIva
    {
        get => _precoFilhoSemIva;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_precoFilhoSemIva, value))
            {
                _precoFilhoSemIva = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    string _codigoArtigo = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 10).ToUpper();
    public string CodigoArtigo
    {
        get => _codigoArtigo;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_codigoArtigo, value))
            {
                _codigoArtigo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instances of this class are placed in a `BindingList` which is assigned to the `DataSource` property of `dgv_Filho` and caused the DGV to update whenever the Refresh method is called.

[image: Change Iva]

[image: Change Descricao]

[image: Change Preco]

---

**Initializations**

The only interaction that should be necessary with the DGV is to initialize the columns and bindings properly in the `MainForm` override for the `Load` event. This is also where we bind the combo box to a static value for Iva that can be used by the calculation for the row items.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    initDataGridView();
    initComboBox();
}
```

```
private void initDataGridView()
{
    dgv_Filho.DataSource = DataSource;
    DataSource.ListChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
        {
            dgv_Filho.Refresh();
        }
    };
    // Add one or more items to autogenerate the columns.
    Random randomPriceGen = new Random(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        var preco = i == 1 ? 1.0m : (decimal)randomPriceGen.NextDouble() * 100;
        DataSource.Add(new Articulo
        {
            Descricao = $"Articulo {(char)('A' + (i - 1))}",
            Medida = i,
            PrecoFilhoSemIva = preco,
        });
    }
    // Do a little column formatting
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv_Filho.Columns)
    {
        switch (column.Name)
        {
            case nameof(Articulo.Descricao):
                column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                column.MinimumWidth = 120;
                break;
            case nameof(Articulo.Medida):
            case nameof(Articulo.PrecoFilhoSemIva):
            case nameof(Articulo.PrecoFilhoComIva):
                column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F2";
                column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                break;
            default:
                column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
private void initComboBox()
{
    cb_Iva.SelectedIndex = 0;
    cb_Iva.SelectedIndexChanged += onIvaSelected;
    cb_Iva.KeyDown += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if( e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        onIvaSelected(sender, e);
    };
    onIvaSelected(cb_Iva, EventArgs.Empty);

    void onIvaSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(cb_Iva.Text.Replace("%", string.Empty), out decimal iva))
        {
            Iva = iva / 100m;
            dgv_Filho.Refresh();
            cb_Iva.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
        }
        else cb_Iva.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/datagridview_dynamic_cell_calculation.git) this sample.